# Отсутствие перевода названия месяца на странице репутации

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex, мобильная-версия

В мобильной версии сайта отсутствует перевод названия месяца на странице просмотра репутации (профиль - активность - репутация):

> [image: репутация по датам]

Единственно [упоминание "Sep"](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261806?key=f04aa7019c490474fa3ce16e93501b57) в transifex имеет перевод, значит в данном случае строка не берется из transifex.

Comment: Завёл [баг на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324625/339911).