# Описание раздела Голоса и вкладка Репутация, мобильная версия

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, мобильная-версия

При просмотре [профиля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/224820/sasha-omelchenko) из мобильного браузера в разделе Голоса можно найти непереведённый фрагмент текста:

> Of the votes cast, %num% were up-votes and %num% were down-votes. %Username% voted on questions % times and %times on answers.

---

Также, при просмотре с мобильного вкладки [Репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/224820/sasha-omelchenko?tab=reputation) в профиле, видно, что переведена только первая строка, а именно СЕГОДНЯ, далее идут даты на англ.: MAR 27, MAR 26 и т. д.

Comment: По поводу месяца есть [отдельный баг](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3812/176217).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это одна из нескольких строк, которую разработчики не смогли (в моей интерпретации: не захотели) разбить хотя бы на два предложения в базе Transifex, чтобы облегчить труд по переводу. В текущей версии [упомянутая строка](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/108334622?key=b6475232202bb96802a83f457ea79900) требует `3 * 3 * 3 * 3 = 81` комбинации для перевода (из-за необходимости учёта различных множественных форм в окончаниях), и я считаю это издевательством над переводчиком. При разбиении на 2 предложения таких комбинаций было бы всего `3 * 3 + 3 * 3 = 18`.

Некоторый контекст можно почерпнуть из [чата](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35494541#35494541). Но основной посыл в том, что разбиение невозможно из-за особенностей **японского** языка. Что-то там такого, что принципиально нельзя разбить строку на два предложения - я не понимаю. Особенно учитывая, что исходная строка фактически представляет уже два предложения (видно разделительную точку).

Можно сделать единый перевод для всех строк, если выбрать такой вариант, который не требует различных форм. [Подобный вариант уже был ранее.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4353/176217) Тогда обновить все строки будет несколько проще, но всё равно достаточно рутинно. Однако такой способ я не считаю правильным.

Строки были переведены и утверждены. Нужно дождаться подгрузки и обновления сайта.